# Opencart not showing the total price of a product

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am working on opencart. I have a problem that

I have a product of price of `INR 1300` on which `Item CST (tax)` is levied as 5% which is INR. When I add this product in cart then it should show the total price as 1300+65=1365. But in opencart it is showing only INR 65.

It was all of a sudden. Yesterday night it was working fine but in morning I saw the problem. For your better understanding I am attaching the screenshot

[image]

Please help me guys, what mistake I had made ?

Answer (score 1):

I think You need enable Sub-Total in admin. You can find this in section Order Totals

Comment: When I enable this then the total goes to zero